# GHCi not seeing my module

Tags: haskell, module

A made a module Timeit. I can't import it to GHCi.
Module:

```
module Timeit (timeit, timeCatch) where
import Data.Time.Clock

timeit::IO ()->IO (Float)
timeit io=do
    (time,())<-timeCatch io
    return time

timeCatch::IO (a)->IO (Float,a)
timeCatch io=do
    start  <-getCurrentTime
    result <-io
    end    <-getCurrentTime
    return $! (realToFrac (diffUTCTime end start), result)

test=do
    putStrLn "What is your name?"
    name <- getLine
    putStrLn $ "Your name is "++name++"."
```

GHCi:

```
theking@ChrisLaptopUbuntu1304:~/Desktop/Haskell$ cd ~/Desktop/Haskell/; ghci
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> import Timeit

<no location info>:
    Could not find module `Timeit'
    Perhaps you meant Time (needs flag -package haskell98-2.0.0.2)
```

I am able to import it into my other programs, just not GHCi.

Note: Am I a haskell noob.

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls | grep hs`

Answer (score 3):

In order for a module to be imported by GHCi, you have to make sure a few things are true.

First, are you in the same directory? By default GHCi will only search the current directory for modules.

Second, have you added the module header? Your code should start with

```
 module Timeit where
 ...
```

Third, your file must actually be named `Timeit.hs` (with that capitalization).
By default Haskell inserts `module Main where`, which is a problem if your module isn't main.

Last but not least, GHCi seems to require that you use `:l Timeit` at least once. I'm not sure why this is, but once loaded you can remove it from scope with `:m` and then import it to your hearts content.

If you've done these things it should import just fine.

Comment: @PyRulez Then I'm unable to reproduce your error, can you post your code?

Comment: Additionally, if you are just testing the code, you can load it by filename with `:load path/to/file.hs`, but that doesn't work work when you need to import it in other modules.

Comment: I said I am able to import it in other modules.

Comment: @PyRulez use `:l Timeit` before `import ...` this will work. You only have to do it once it seems.

Comment: @jozefg I think you should reorder your answer. The use of `:l` rather than `import` is the important point here.

Answer (score 0):

To import modules from ghci don't use import, rather say

```
:m +TimeIt
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Does one need to compile the module before? The only thing which works for me is `:load TimeIt.hs`.